# Action on one CSS element causes effect on another?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Simple enough question.

For example can I change the style of say `.inner-div` when `.outer-div` is hovered?

```
div.outer-div{}
div.inner-div{}
```

This is just an example, it could just as well be `.inner-div` affects `.outer-div`

I understand this isn't natively supported by CSS, although media queries may do the trick? I'm not sure though? Any ideas on changing an element from another?

Please don't answer with, "You can use JQuery". I'm looking for only CSS methods here.

Comment: You can use JQuery.....hhhhhh (kidding)

Comment: What is the connection between the two divs? It could be possible, depending where they are in the DOM relative to each other. Please provide your HTML. If they are not related to each other, there is no way with CSS.

Comment: Hi bazmegakapa. It's not really a code issue. I'm just looking for ways this can be done.

Comment: @Sean There are several ways to do this, depending on the situation :). See the [CSS spec on selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#combinators). I'm voting to close because the question is too broad in its current state.

Comment: @bazmegakapa Well really I'm looking for many situations, this is something that has bugged me about CSS for a while. One situation is that the `inner-div` resides within the `outer-div`, while another situation would be that `inner-div` standsalone and so does `outer-div` but `outer-div` can still affect `inner-div` and vice versa

Comment: @Sean If you read the spec I linked, you will see what you can do. A parent can affect its children, or siblings can affect each other. Children can't affect parents, that's the nature of CSS. If elements have no DOM relation that you can rely on, you have to use Javascript to add classes to the elements based on user actions.

Comment: @bazmegakapa Chill man. We're all friends here. I have looked over the link and I thank you for the resource.

Comment: @Sean I did not mean any insult :). I am trying to help, sorry if you felt I insulted you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that inner is inside outer, you can use `div.outer-div:hover div.inner-div {}`

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works. But I assume that in order for this to work, that the elements need to have a relation?